# Can HEAD requests be run from the client across domains?

Tags: php, javascript

that is, can I do cross-domain head requests.  I know that I can not do cross domain GET requests as this breaks the same orign policy, but because HEAD requests only return Meta data, and no content, do they have less restrict constraints?

I want to validate URLs and I'd prefer to have the client do this wrather than the server.

**Reference**

http://blog.mostof.it/what-is-a-http-head-request-good-for-some-uses/

Comment: Did you try a head request? What happened? I think you already know the answer, the type of request makes no difference with the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: I'm tired of writing trial and error code just to scrap it when it does not work...b.c. there is not content, the possibility that restrictions are relaxed is plausible.

Comment: You can circumvent the same-origin policy using http://anyorigin.com. If you use jQuery just do `$.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com/get?url=http://stackoverflow.com&callback=some_function', function(data) { $('body').html(data.contents); }`

Comment: ... the server has to be jsonp enabled ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about ... if it isn't no go ... as i mentioned before jsonp and cors require server configuration ... how is a 3rd party app going to have anything to do with this?

Comment: @pure_code.mom I believe that is called the development process! lol

Comment: I'm getting carpal tunnel syndrome from this process...needs to be shorter!